# How to add custom form on checkout page below shipping address using Layout Processor?

Tags: magento2

I am following this tutorial https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_form.html but I am not able to add the form as code looks incomplete to me. I have created the below files:
 - plugin file for layout processor in Model
 - di.xml file for defining this plugin
 - checkout_index_index.xml
 - to use custom form in checkout page I override shipping.html file and added below code.

```
li id="opc-custom-checkout-form"
data-bind="fadeVisible: visible()"
div class="custom-checkout-form"
    div class="step-title"
         translate="'Other information'"
         data-role="title" /
    !-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form') --
    !-- ko template: getTemplate() -->!-- /ko --
    !--/ko--
/div
```

/li

It looks like there is something I am missing in the checkout_index_index.xml file.

Can someone help me out here? Thanks.